# Why does my game in Phaser doesn't recognizes Phaser.GameObjets.Container?

Tags: containers, phaser-framework

Hey i've been trying to input a score text in canvas but gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Container' of undefined.

Here's the code:

```js
class ScoreBox extends Phaser.GameObjets.Container{
    constructor (config){
    //invoke constructor of extended class
        super (config.scene);
    //get scene from parameter and set scene atribute
        this.scene = config.scene;
    //add a text box to the scene
        this.text = this.scene.add.text ( 0, 0, "SCORE: 0");
    //set text origin
        this.text.setOrigin (0.5, 0.5);
    //add the text to the container
        this.add (this.text);
    //add the container to the scene
        this.scene.add.existing (this);
    //Enable score update through emitter
        emitter.on (messageConstants.SCORE_UPDATED, this.scoreUpdated);
    }
    scoreUpdated (){
        this.text.setText ("SCORE: " + model.score);
    }
    
}
```

I'm connecting this to the html but I don't know why doesn't recognizes the container class, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

At least in your example code you have a typo. It should be `Phaser.GameObjects.Container` not `Phaser.GameObjets.Container`